# Ajax Jquery not return the URL after using ActionLink in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I got a scenario:

Here's my ActionResult when ActionLink was Clicked

```
 public PartialViewResult ViewHit(string id, string recordid,string statusSelect,string statusHitSelect)
{
    //some code here....
}
```

The ActionLink where to post after the Button was clicked:

```
public ActionResult SaveUpdate(String statusSelect, string statusHitSelect)
 {

     return PartialView("ViewHitList");
 }
```

Here's the button:

```
<input type="button" value="Save" id="savehit"/>
```

and Here's my Ajax:

```
 $("#savehit").on('click', function () {

            //alert("Button was click!");
            $.ajax({
                type: "post",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                //url: "SelectUpdate?statusSelect=" + statusSelect + '&statusHitSelect=' + statusHitSelect,
                url: "SaveUpdate",
                data: "{'statusSelect':'" + statusSelect + "','statusHitSelect':'" + statusHitSelect + "'}",
                //data:null,
                success: function (response) {
                    if (response != null && response.success) {
                        //InformationMessageSuccess(response.responseText);
                        alert("success");
                    } else {
                        // DoSomethingElse()
                        //InformationMessageFailed(response.responseText);
                        alert("not success");
                    }
                },

            });

        });
```

The problem is, when i hit the save button using debug mode the ActionResult called was the `ViewHit` instead of `SaveUpdate`.

I am wondering why is it happen?

Any great idea is highly appreciated.

Comment: is `savehit` button is inside a form?

Comment: Nothing form element on my save button. @jeric

Comment: Thanks for the answers below.. but unfortunately doesn't solved the issue. Don't know why... You can try to simulate the problem guy's do it from the start with `ActionLink`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to avoid default action of the event by using `event.preventDefault()`

```
$("#savehit").on('click', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    //alert("Button was click!");
    $.ajax({
        type: "post",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        //url: "SelectUpdate?statusSelect=" + statusSelect + '&statusHitSelect=' + statusHitSelect,
        url: "@Url.Action("SaveUpdate", "Home")",
        data: "{'statusSelect':'" + statusSelect + "','statusHitSelect':'" + statusHitSelect + "'}",
        //data:null,
        success: function (response) {
            if (response != null && response.success) {
                //InformationMessageSuccess(response.responseText);
                alert("success");
            } else {
                // DoSomethingElse()
                //InformationMessageFailed(response.responseText);
                alert("not success");
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Also iv'e tried this `url: "Home/SaveUpdate",` but no luck.

Comment: as my investigation the url added the old one like `http://localhost:6487/Home/ViewHit/Home/SaveUpdate`. it's wierd, don't know why.

Comment: You can try to use UrlHelper. try my updated answer. just be sure that 'SaveUpdate' is in `Home` controller

Answer (score 1):

SaveUpdate is not post type please add attribute [HttpPost] at the top of the controller method like

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SaveUpdate(String statusSelect, string statusHitSelect)
 {

     return PartialView("ViewHitList");
 }
```

I have changed the ajax call like bellow and it the SaveUpdate method. Bellow is the ajax call.

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#savehit").on('click', function () {
            var statusSelectData="statusSelect";
            var statusHitSelectData="statusHitSelect";
            var postData = {
                statusSelect: statusSelectData,
                statusHitSelect: statusHitSelectData
            }
            //alert("Button was click!");
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/Home/SaveUpdate",
                data: postData,
                //data:null,
                success: function (response) {
                    if (response != null && response.success) {
                        //InformationMessageSuccess(response.responseText);
                        alert("success");
                    } else {
                        // DoSomethingElse()
                        //InformationMessageFailed(response.responseText);
                        alert("not success");
                    }
                },

            });

        });
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Add the [HttpPost] attribute to the SaveUpdate action
2. In the ajax, change the URL to url: "ControllerName/SaveUpdate"
3. Since you are expecting a boolean result (JSON) back to your page as the ajax response, simply return a jsonResult (true/false)

Comment: Thanks for your idea @Unni